# Can you store the results of a query into a TEXT (or any string-like data type) variable when writing Stored Routines in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I want to know if I can store the results of a query into a string-like variable in an stored routine in a MySQL database inside of a stored routine that I'm writing.

@The Scrum Meister:

Here's what I have right now:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE `mydb`.`markCompanyAsHavingInactiveEmployees` ()
BEGIN
    DECLARE company TEXT;
    SET @company := 'SELECT company FROM Employees WHERE status=2';
    -- Can I make an array inside of stored procedures?
END
```

It's not complete, and I don't know if it'll get what I want done.  But, there it is.

@siride:

What I'm trying to do is to set a field in a record from the Company table to a certain value, which would depend on what's found in the records of the Employee table.

Here's my pseudo code for what I'm trying to do:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE `mydb`.`markCompanyAsHavingInactiveEmployees` ()
BEGIN
    DECLARE companies TEXT;
    SET @companies := 'SELECT company FROM Employees WHERE status=2';
DECLARE i INT;
WHILE(i<=companies.length)
{
    DECLARE company TEXT;
    company = "";
    if(companies.charAt(i)!='\n')   company.concat(companies.charAt(i));
    DECLARE stmt TEXT;
    stmt = CONCAT('UPDATE Companies SET HaveInactiveEmployees=1 WHERE name=\'', company, '\'');
    i++;
}
END
```

I don't think that anything like this will actually work in a MySQL routine, but this is what I would do if I could.

Comment: Could you please give a example of what you are trying to do? the question is a bit unclear. What do you want to do with the results-string?

Comment: previously you are 14%, one accept answer out of nine questions

Comment: But, by the time that you and I posted I had already accepted answers for all but 3 questions.  It's weird, though, how I calculated 67% b/c of my 2:3 ask and accept ratio, but it says 86% next to my name.  That's a bit generous I think!

Comment: @Liars_Paradox I updated my answer. I just noticed that I left this question unresolved. I hope my answer is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can't make arrays inside stored procedures, but you can create temporary tables (with the right permissions, of course).

More to your main question, do you want to run the query and somehow concatenate the results into a single string, perhaps delimited by something?  If that's the case, you could have something like this inside your stored procedure:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(company SEPARATOR '|') INTO company
FROM Employees WHERE status = 2
GROUP BY status;
```

This will give you a single string of the form "Acme Products, Inc.|Microsoft|Apple|...".

I don't know if this solves your problem, since, as some of the commentors on the question noted, we aren't sure what the exact problem is.  But hopefully it helps you on your quest.

EDIT: I looked at your edit (finally) and it looks like you are trying to do with dynamic SQL what you can do in a single query. I'm guessing you come from a heavy programming background and aren't used to the relational logic that you would use in a database. Here's an example of your request done in a single query:

```
UPDATE Companies
JOIN Employees
  ON Employees.company = Companies.name
SET Companies.HaveInactiveEmployees = 1
WHERE Employees.status = 2
```

You'll probably want to read the MySQL documentation for UPDATE statements (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html) to get a better understanding of what's going on here. But basically, we are joining the Companies and Employees tables on the company name and then from the resulting table (a join basically produces a new table), we are selecting the rows where the status field (from the Employees part of the join table) is 2, and for each of those rows, we update the HaveInactiveEmployees field to be 1.

Note that this isn't the only way to do this. Based on the semantics of your query, it seems like you want to update all companies to indicate whether they have any inactive employees. You can express it like this instead:

```
UPDATE Companies
SET HaveInactiveEmployees = 1
WHERE Companies.name IN(SELECT company FROM Employees WHERE status = 2)
```

This does the same thing, but it makes it more clear that you are looking for the company name for each employee that is inactive (I assume that's what status 2 means). Once you have that list of names, you update all the company entries that have names in that list.

To put this in programming perspective, we have one loop that constructs an array with a list of company names, and then we have another for loop that goes through each company and sets the HaveInactiveEmployees field to 1 if the company's name is in the array we just constructed. Subqueries are basically nested loops. Joins are also nested loops, but can be more efficient. This query, for example, will run slower than the query above, but only because MySQL isn't smart enough to optimize it properly. The logic is more or less the same and a good DB engine would produce the same execution plan for both queries.